# Fastest C# IoC container when scanning and auto registering by convention

Tags: c#, performance, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have a big old solution (63 projects) that uses Unity to

```
Scan(scanner =>
        {
            scanner.AssemblyContaining<ServiceRegistry>();
            scanner.WithNamingConvention();

            scanner.ExcludeType<ModuleManager>();
        });
```

But I would like to speed up loading the application, but I cant really find any benchmark that shows if other frameworks are faster at scanning my assemplys and auto registering all types.

I found http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison which shows a lot of frameworks that are faster, but not with assemply scanning, and it might not be easy to get faster performance with assemply scanning as I presume it requires slow reflection?

Comment: What's the performance difference between using the Unity scanning facility and doing this yourself by iterating the assemblies and registering those types? With a massive solution with 64 projects you might have hit the max, although registration of a component takes some time as well because of the amount of verification that needs to be done. Some containers might do that faster. Eitherway, it's good to see what the overhead of iterating the assemblies is to know whether switching containers would even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, assemblies are Loaded, then on the first access to it, the list of classes names is retrieved. This process is very fast and requires no heavy reflection. The time consumed for loading a DLL over the network is more important.

But even if some IoC seems slow on such benchmarks, I guaranty you that a "slow" IoC Framework like MEF (which I use) is really fast to find, compose and recompose things. You will not notice any lag, event with hundreds of class.

The bottleneck can be when instantiating ten thousands of classes in a loop. In this case, the way the IoC instantiates is critical, but if you uses an IoC to instantiates 10 000's objects, you have a design problem, not a performance one.

Moreover, choosing a IoC FW is more likely a feature and ease of use question, than a performance one, since most of IoC fw's are suitable even for enormous projects.

Comment: We have a big WPF application that has modules, I have no clue how many objects are being registered, but its a lot, how would you propose I do it then to make it faster if not having the IoC container registering them?

Comment: You can't be faster with an IoC than the normal way to instantiate thing by calling their constructor. There's an performance overhead by using any IoC. But by using an IoC, you only instantiate the things you need, when you need them. So there's a balance between both approches. I really think you should first look at the way of using different IoC, and then make your choose. Personally I use MEF on really big projects with a lot of plugins, and I never have had performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a custom scanning implementation yourself is not very difficult. Here is a simple one that we use:

```
internal class CommonConventions
{
    public static void RegisterDefaultConventions(
        Action<Type, Type> registerMethod, 
        Assembly[] interfaceAssemblies, 
        Assembly[] implementationAssemblies, 
        Type[] excludeTypes,
        string excludeRegEx)
    {
        List<Type> interfaces = new List<Type>();

        foreach (var assembly in interfaceAssemblies)
            interfaces.AddRange(GetInterfaces(assembly));

        foreach (var interfaceType in interfaces)
        {
            if (!IsExcludedType(interfaceType, excludeTypes, excludeRegEx))
            {
                List<Type> implementations = new List<Type>();

                foreach (var assembly in implementationAssemblies)
                    implementations.AddRange(GetImplementationsOfInterface(assembly, interfaceType).Where(implementation => !IsExcludedType(implementation, excludeTypes, excludeRegEx)).ToArray());

                // Prefer the default name ITypeName = TypeName
                Type implementationType = implementations.Where(implementation => IsDefaultType(interfaceType, implementation)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (implementationType == null)
                {
                    // Fall back on ITypeName = ITypeNameAdapter
                    implementationType = implementations.Where(implementation => IsAdapterType(interfaceType, implementation)).FirstOrDefault();
                }

                if (implementationType != null)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Auto registration of {1} : {0}", interfaceType.Name, implementationType.Name);
                    registerMethod(interfaceType, implementationType);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void RegisterAllImplementationsOfInterface(
        Action<Type, Type> registerMethod,
        Type[] interfaceTypes,
        Assembly[] implementationAssemblies,
        Type[] excludeTypes,
        string excludeRegEx)
    {
        foreach (var interfaceType in interfaceTypes)
        {
            List<Type> implementations = new List<Type>();

            foreach (var assembly in implementationAssemblies)
                implementations.AddRange(GetImplementationsOfInterface(assembly, interfaceType));

            foreach (var implementationType in implementations)
            {
                if (!IsExcludedType(implementationType, excludeTypes, excludeRegEx))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Auto registration of {1} : {0}", interfaceType.Name, implementationType.Name);
                    registerMethod(interfaceType, implementationType);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static bool IsExcludedType(Type type, Type[] excludeTypes, string excludeRegEx)
    {
        return IsExcludedType(type, excludeTypes) || IsExcludedType(type, excludeRegEx) || IsExcludedType(type);
    }

    private static bool IsExcludedType(Type type, Type[] excludeTypes)
    {
        return excludeTypes.Contains(type);
    }

    private static bool IsExcludedType(Type type, string excludeRegEx)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(excludeRegEx)) return false;
        return Regex.Match(type.Name, excludeRegEx, RegexOptions.Compiled).Success;
    }

    private static bool IsExcludedType(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MvcSiteMapProvider.DI.ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute), false).Length > 0;  
    }

    private static bool IsDefaultType(Type interfaceType, Type implementationType)
    {
        return interfaceType.Name.Equals("I" + implementationType.Name);
    }

    private static bool IsAdapterType(Type interfaceType, Type implementationType)
    {
        return implementationType.Name.EndsWith("Adapter") &&
            interfaceType.Name.Equals("I" + implementationType.Name.Substring(0, implementationType.Name.Length - 7));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfaces(Assembly assembly)
    {
        return assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsInterface);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Type> GetImplementationsOfInterface(Assembly assembly, Type interfaceType)
    {
        return assembly.GetTypes().Where(t =>
            !t.IsInterface &&
            !t.IsAbstract &&
            interfaceType.IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
            t.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Any(type => type.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType).All(p => (p.IsInterface || p.IsClass) && p != typeof(string))));
    }
}
```

You can read the documentation about what each of the public members does [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/CodeAsConfiguration/Shared/DI/CommonConventions.cs).

These conventions are then used like this:

```
// Matching type name (I[TypeName] = [TypeName]) or matching type name + suffix Adapter (I[TypeName] = [TypeName]Adapter)
// and not decorated with the [ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute].
CommonConventions.RegisterDefaultConventions(
    (interfaceType, implementationType) => this.Container.RegisterType(
        interfaceType, implementationType, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()),
    new Assembly[] { siteMapProviderAssembly },
    allAssemblies,
    excludeTypes,
    string.Empty);

// Multiple implementations of strategy based extension points (and not decorated with [ExcludeFromAutoRegistrationAttribute]).
CommonConventions.RegisterAllImplementationsOfInterface(
    (interfaceType, implementationType) => this.Container.RegisterType(
        interfaceType, implementationType, implementationType.Name, 
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()),
    multipleImplementationTypes,
    allAssemblies,
    excludeTypes,
    string.Empty);
```

The above won't solve your problem, but is intended to point you in the right direction with creating your own conventions.

The bottleneck you are most likely seeing is going through 64 different assemblies with reflection in order to find all of the types that match a particular interface. In reality the implementations only occur in a few (or one) assembly. I suggest that you use a custom attribute to narrow down this selection process so only the relevant (implementation) assemblies are scanned for each interface.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Interface, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class AutoRegistrationIncludeAssembliesAttribute
    : Attribute
{
    public AutoRegistrationIncludeAssembliesAttribute(params string[] assemblies)
    {
        this.Assemblies = assemblies;
    }

    public string[] Assemblies { get; private set; }
}
```

Then in each of your interfaces, add the attribute with only the assembly names you will find the implementations in.

```
[AutoRegistrationIncludeAssemblies("Assembly1", "Assembly2")]
public interface ISomeInterface
{
}
```

And in your custom convention, filter the assemblies that are scanned for implementations.

```
var includeAssemblies = (AutoRegistrationIncludeAssembliesAttribute)interfaceType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AutoRegistrationIncludeAssembliesAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
if (includeAssemblies != null)
{
    var filteredImplementationAssemblies = implementationAssemblies.Where(a => includeAssemblies.Assemblies.Contains(a.FullName));
}
```

You may want to flip this around and make an `AutoRegistrationExcludeAssembliesAttribute` if you want unknown assemblies that are part of the project to be scanned in case you are not in control of all of the potential locations where an interface might be implemented.

Another thing that could really speed things up would be to use the conventions as part of your MSBuild process that generate a code file (DI module) that contains all of the explicit registrations based on the convention prior to the compile step. That way, you still only have to maintain conventions, but during runtime all of the types will be registered explicitly so no Reflection will be used during application startup.